# How to get store config inside a theme template

Tags: magento2, theme, system-config

I am trying to add the store's phone number setup in **Stores > Configuration > General > General > Store Information** to the header in my theme. In a module I think this could be done using `getValue()` in `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` but I cannot see a way how to use this inside a theme. So far I have added this to default.xml

```
 <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.phone.number" template="Magento_Theme::phone.phtml" />
 </referenceContainer>
```

but I do not know how to get the phone number inside `phone.phtml`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you create your own block, which will extend the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class.

As the `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` is part of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock` (the parent of the `Template` class) declared in `$_scopeConfig`, you can add the following function to your custom block:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return $this->_scopeConfig;
}
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
$block->getConfig()->getValue('value/you/need');
```

Don't forget to update your layout like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
      <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\View\Element\Template" name="store.phone.number" template="Magento_Theme::phone.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Having to create a module to work with the theme doesn't seem a very elegant way of doing it (although it looks like it might be the only way). Surely this will cause problems for theme developers that are publishing themes

Comment: @Alex yes using the object manager directly is definitely easier but it is not recommended to use it directly. So there's two options, quick and dirty or slow and clean ^^

Comment: @Alex Theme developers have always shipped their themes with theme specific modules and I don't know of any problems. It actually is an elegant solution. Having much PHP code in templates isn't.

Answer (score 6):

We can directly get a store config in the template by getting instance of `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfig`:

```
 \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
  ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
  ->getValue('value/you/need');
```

Technically, when someone asks for an instance of `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`, we will give it an instance of the `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfig`.
For example, we can get the default setting for grid or list mode:

```
$productListMode = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
   ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
   ->getValue('catalog/frontend/list_mode');
```

**Note:** **Avoiding Using Object Manager directly**. We should keep our templates clean. Try to add config to the block. Should follow the @Raphael answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works for catalog/frontend/list_mode like in your example but is returning null for general/store_information/phone

Comment: Did you set the phone number for your store? I can get the phone number of store: `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
    ->getValue('general/store_information/phone');`

Comment: Yeh I added in Stores > Configuration > General > General > Store Information. Tried a default value and for the website/store

Comment: Please try to re-index and clear cache.

Comment: I've got it pulling the default phone number now but is ignoring the one set in the store/website config. Have you tried this?

Comment: Nevermind, just had to add second parameter to getValue. Thanks for the help

Comment: How do you define website or storeview using this approach?

Comment: Nvm I found it: ``        $value = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')
            ->getValue($config, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store_id);``

Answer (score 2):

Try this on Block, it is working for me after many search

> $isEnabled = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
>   ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')    ->getValue('section/group/field');